# inserting radio button value in database in c#.net

Tags: c#

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        string Sql_radio = "Insert Into tb1(name)Values ('Yes')";
    }

    if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        string Sql_radio = "Insert Into tb1(name)Values ('no')";
    }

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Sql_radio, con);


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted sucessfully");
}
```

hello.. i am developing a winform application, now i have two radio buttons as you can see in the above code.

i want that if user `selects radiobutton1` then `yes` should get inserted in the database and if user `selects radiobutton2` then it should `insert no` in the databse.

i have aplied following condition but it is giving an error that the

> name Sql_radio does not exist in the current context

can anyone please tell me the correct way to do the above code?

Comment: your object of **Sql_radio** is limited to if condition scope only. So I would suggest to declare it globally and use the same object in both conditions. See my answer for the same.

Comment: what is the data type of `name` column in your database table ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to declare string `Sql_radio` globally in the code for `btnUpdate_Click` function.

See following:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string Sql_radio="";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {

            Sql_radio = "Insert Into tb1(name)Values ('Yes')";

        }
        if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {

            Sql_radio = "Insert Into tb1(name)Values ('no')";

        }
         OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Sql_radio, con);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Inserted sucessfully");

    }
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use a stored procedure and not inline sql. Also put a try catch around the code will help you debug - error fix issues.

Comment: @LairdStreak why have you commented this under my answer bro??? i have just corrected his piece of code which was having error :)

Comment: @LairdStreak ok bro, not an issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare `string Sql_radio` out of `If`

```
Try
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    string Sql_radio = ""; 
    if(RadioButton1.Checked)
    {
     Sql_radio = "Insert Into tb1(name)Values ('Yes')";
    }
    else if(RadioButton2.Checked)
    {
     Sql_radio = "Insert Into tb1(name)Values ('No')";
    }
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Sql_radio, con);


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted sucessfully");
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: this is not the issue bro...issue is of string declaration

Comment: what should be passed den?

Comment: @user3181292 Check updated code  Declaration Of Sql_radio is the problem

Comment: @user3181292 try above code and check what error you getting now

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    string Sql_radio = "";
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        Sql_radio = "Insert Into tb1(name)Values ('Yes')";
    }
    if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        Sql_radio = "Insert Into tb1(name)Values ('no')";
    }
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Sql_radio, con);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted sucessfully");
}
```

Scope of `Sql_radio` is expired after the `if` snippets. Move the declaration to method scope and everything will be fine.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? If it is a DB error please ask a different question. Otherwise my solution should work for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your string outside of `if condition` ,

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    string Sql_radio = String.Empty;
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {

         Sql_radio = "Insert Into tb1(name)Values ('Yes')";

    }
    if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {

        Sql_radio = "Insert Into tb1(name)Values ('no')";

    }
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Sql_radio, con);


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted sucessfully");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the **string Sql_radio** out of if condition as mentioned below :

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    con.Open();

    var Sql_radio = string.Empty;

    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        Sql_radio = "Insert Into tb1(name)Values ('Yes')";
    }

    if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        Sql_radio = "Insert Into tb1(name)Values ('no')";
    }

    var cmd = new OleDbCommand(Sql_radio, con);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted sucessfully");
}
```